# I'm using fullpage.js and want to hide the navigation option for small screens (max-width: 700px)

Tags: function, constructor, media-queries, fullpage.js

This is the script to call fullpage.js and set the options:

```
  <script>
    new fullpage('#fullpage', {
      //options here
      autoScrolling: true,
      scrollHorizontally: true,
      navigation: true,  
    });
  </script>
```

So I want to make navigation false  when for the view-port is less than 700px

I tried this but didn't work

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    fullpage('#fullpage', { navigation: true,
});
  } else {
   fullpage('#fullpage', { navigation: false,
});
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using normal CSS media queries?

```
@media screen and (max-height: 700px){
  #fp-nav{ 
   display: none;
  }
}
```